# Convert datetime to month in number and year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a datetime e.g. 2014-04-24 00:28:53.897 and want to convert this in a select query to month in number and year - 4 2014.

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MM yyyy')
```

replace getdate with you datetime column

Hope it help you.

Comment: Probably the best answer :)

Comment: May be you need to mention this won't below **sql server 2012**

Comment: +1, but OP would probably want  `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'M yyyy')` this more because their example output does not have the leading zero on the month.

Comment: i was never really looking at the FORMAT() function but looks nice! short and clear. +1 :)

Comment: for completion: for great number of rows (in my test 50K) format function seems to be a lot slower than using "manual" concatenation... just as information if you run into performance-troubles...

Answer (score 4):

Use DATEPART

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(mm,datefield),' ',DATEPART(yyyy,datefield)) AS monthyear
FROM yourtable
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c896/7/0

Comment: this will NOT work! The result for today (2015-05-11) will be an integer number 2020, since your command will calculate 2015+5!

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this: (where you replace GETDATE() with your date/datetime column)

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following on SQL Server 2012 and above (or others that provide `CONCAT`):

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(mm,dateField),' ',DATEPART(yyyy,dateField))
AS MONTH_YEAR
FROM TABLENAME;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set into a format.
declare @d datetime='2014-04-24 00:28:53.897'
select FORMAT(@d, 'MM yyyy')

[For more information, visit here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
/* sql code */
--if you have datetime as text use this to convert to date
--select cast('2014-04-24 00:28:53.897' as date)
select convert(varchar(2), month(cast('2014-04-24 00:28:53.897' as date))) + ' ' + convert(char(4), year(cast('2014-04-24 00:28:53.897' as date)))

--if you have datetime field already use this
select convert(varchar(2), month(getdate())) + ' ' + convert(char(4), year(getdate()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DATEPART For this

```
SELECT Convert(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(mm,yourfield),111) + '  ' + 
Convert(VARCHAR(10),DATEPART(yyyy,yourfield),111) AS outputmonthyear
FROM yourtableName
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa887/7

DATEPART Definition and Usage

The DATEPART() function is used to return a single part of a date/time, such as year, month, day, hour, minute, etc.

Syntax DATEPART(datepart,date) Where date is a valid date expression.

for more details please Visit

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp

Comment: Same here as for Matt's solution: You have to convert each datepart to varchar, otherwise sql server will interpret the "+" as mathematical addition and will calculate e.g. 2015+5 = 2020